# Erro em referência de Assembly

Tags: c#

Estou tentando adicionar uma referência ao meu projeto, porém quando adiciono e executo o projeto apresenta esse erro:

> Não foi possível carregar o arquivo ou assembly 'WaitWindow',
>   Version=1.0.6164.26027, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ou uma
>   de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa  de se carregar um
>   programa com um formato incorreto.

Achei outros posts com erros semelhantes porém nenhum solucionou meu problema

Comment: Como você adicionou a referência? Baixou a DLL e vinculou manualmente? Ou baixou pelo nuget?

Comment: adicionei manualmente pois não tinha no nuget, mas já encontrei o erro, era uma versão 64bit sendo q minha maquina é 32bit, obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jeremias, isso pode acontecer, se voce estiver carregando uma dll 32bits para um projeto 64bits ou configurado para ambos.
Neste caso voce deve alterar a plataforma target para x86 nas propriedades do projeto.

Comment: Obrigado Alexandre, a dll era 64bit e meu projeto é 32bit, obrigado